# Extracting all patterns from pandas data frame column (python3)

Tags: python, regex

I’m using jupyter notebook (python 3). I’m trying to extract from pandas data frame keywords from my list. I will have around 50 keywords in the list.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

rgx_words1 = ['algaecid','algaecide','algaecides','anti-bakterien']

 

pattern = "\\b("+'|'.join(rgx_words1)+")\\b"

re_patt = re.compile(pattern)

 

pattern2 = "("+'|'.join(rgx_words1)+")"

re_patt2 = re.compile(pattern2)

 

data = [[1, 'I, will, find, algaecide, dd, algaecid, algaecides'], [2, 'fff, algaecid, dd, algaecide'], [3, 'ssssalgaecidllll, algaecides']]

  

# Create the pandas DataFrame

mydf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text'])

 

mydf['matches'] = mydf.apply(lambda x : re.findall(re_patt,x['text']),axis=1)

mydf['matches2'] = mydf.apply(lambda x : re.findall(re_patt2,x['text']),axis=1)
```

With re_patt I’m extracting exact words and I’m getting correct results. In id 1 my output is algaecide, algaecid, algaecides. With re_patt2 I would like to have all patterns like ‘'ssssalgaecidllll’ with wanted output ‘algaecid’. Output with re_patt2 in id 1 is algaecid, algaecid, algaecid and my wanted output is algaecide, algaecid, algaecides.
I would be grateful for any advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `pattern2` to optionally match non whitespace chars except a comma `[^\s,]*` at the left and the right.

```
pattern2 = "[^\s,]*(?:"+'|'.join(rgx_words1)+")[^\s,]*"
```

The code could look like

```
import pandas as pd
import re

rgx_words1 = ['algaecid','algaecide','algaecides','anti-bakterien']

pattern = "\\b("+'|'.join(rgx_words1)+")\\b"
re_patt = re.compile(pattern)

pattern2 = "[^\s,]*(?:"+'|'.join(rgx_words1)+")[^\s,]*"
re_patt2 = re.compile(pattern2)

data = [[1, 'I, will, find, algaecide, dd, algaecid, algaecides'], [2, 'fff, algaecid, dd, algaecide'], [3, 'ssssalgaecidllll, algaecides']]
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text'])

mydf['matches'] = mydf.apply(lambda x : re.findall(re_patt, x['text']), axis=1)
mydf['matches2'] = mydf.apply(lambda x : re.findall(re_patt2, x['text']), axis=1)

print(mydf)
```

Output

```
   id                                               text                            matches                           matches2
0   1  I, will, find, algaecide, dd, algaecid, algaec...  [algaecide, algaecid, algaecides]  [algaecide, algaecid, algaecides]
1   2                       fff, algaecid, dd, algaecide              [algaecid, algaecide]              [algaecid, algaecide]
2   3                       ssssalgaecidllll, algaecides                       [algaecides]     [ssssalgaecidllll, algaecides]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get for example in id 3 "ssssalgaecidlll" output in column matches2 "algaecid" and not "ssssalgaecidlll"?

Comment: @DinkoJantoš You could do that by reordening the words like `rgx_words1 = ['algaecides','algaecide','algaecid','anti-bakterien']` and then just joining the words with a pipe like `pattern2 = '|'.join(rgx_words1)`

Comment: I did this: rgx_words1.sort(key=len,reverse=True)
 
['anti-bakterien', 'algaecides', 'algaecide', 'algaecid']
 
mypatt = '|'.join(rgx_words1)
re_mypatt = re.compile(mypatt)
 
mydf['matches3'] = mydf.apply(lambda x : re.findall(re_mypatt, x['text']), axis=1)
 
In my new column matches3 I have output algaecid, algaecid and in column matches2 output is ssssalgaecidllll, algaecides. For word ssssalgaecidllll my output algaecide is correct but for word algaecides my output is algaecide and I would need algaecides.

Comment: @DinkoJantoš If you are joining the words with `|` only, the alternation will match the first one. After the sort, the alternatives look like this `anti-bakterien|algaecides|algaecide|algaecid` so it will first match `algaecides` if it can.

Comment: so is there any solution? Or this is wrong -> pattern2 = '|'.join(rgx_words1)? Can I have output from word 'ssssalgaecidesllll' --> algaecides and not algaecid?

Comment: @DinkoJantoš It does give you `algaecides`. Note that in the example data there is `[3, 'ssssalgaecidllll, algaecides']` and not `[3, 'ssssalgaecidesllll, algaecides']`

Comment: I was wrong. I will explain. With pattern2 = "[^\s,]*(?:"+'|'.join(rgx_words1)+")[^\s,]*"

re_patt2 = re.compile(pattern2) my output is [ssssalgaecidllll, algaecides]. With mypatt = '|'.join(rgx_words1)

re_mypatt = re.compile(mypatt) my output is [algaecid, algaecid] and my wanted output would be [algaecid, algaecides]. I don't know if this is possible?